# Xili language plugin not showing language flag

Tags: plugins, multi-language, icon

I just updated my wordpress version to 3.4.2 and I installed xili-language plugin v. 2.8.1
Everything works quite nice except one detail - I have 2 languages pl & english. I uploaded icon for polish flag to *../twentyten-xili/images/flags* where I have other flags, but wordpress won't show it in navigation menu. Meantime it is showing flag for english. I named file pl_pl.png and it has the same width and height as other flags. What is more curious - I did it on localhost (but with twentyeleven-xili theme) and it worked smoothly.
Any idea?

edit: link to plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-language/

Comment: Interesting plugin... Please, add a [link to the plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-language/) when writing a Question. ::::: Also, it's not clear what this phrase *"but with twentyeleven-xili theme"* has to do with the previous mention of *"../twentyeleven-xili/images/flags"*. ::::: IMO, if it works locally and not online, you should [debug](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=debug) it.

Comment: one is twentyten another one is twentyeleven (2010 and 2011) :)

Comment: Oh, I misread those "Twenties"... Anyway, IMO, the Question as it is now seems *[too localized](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close)*. Take a look at your browser's inspector, it should be throwing an error, much probably "file not found", that shall give you a hint on how to fix the issue. Also, generally the naming convention is "pl_PL", language/country, being the former in uppercase.